# Oracle apex items empty space when specifying item width

Tags: oracle, frontend, oracle-apex

I am trying to position 2 items side by side, but one item has a fixed width of 2 characters and when the width is specified the items are not "glued" together in runtime.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this?

I am using Oracle APEX 21.2.8

Answer (score 0):

This depends on several settings. On 22.2 this works:

- Region of type "Standard", Region template options > item spacing: None
- Item template options for 1st Page Item > right margin: None
- Item template options for 2nd Page Item > left margin: None
- For both items I used the "floating" template.

Result:

[image]

If this doesn't work then please provide exact details of your setup: what region type, what templates for the page items, etc